# regex to match a string and avoid an interval

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex, text-parsing

I am working in javascript/jquery and
I have this STRING:
(Notice that this is a STRING containing Html and so i can't just do $('.myClass').whatever :))

"

```
<div class="myClass"> asd class 2 a a a a a a </div>   class
<div class="myClass"> class asd df </div>
<div class="myClass"> class </div>
<div class="myClass"> class sdf class aa </div>
<div class="myClass">class sdf class aa </div>
```

"

i wanna make a regexp that matches only a certain word but not in the html tags.
for example if my word is "class" i want to match this:
(the [] enclosure is a match)
"

```
<div class="myClass"> asd [class] 2 a a a a a a </div>   class
<div class="myClass"> [class] asd df </div>
<div class="myClass"> [class] </div>
<div class="myClass"> [class] sdf [class] aa </div>
<div class="myClass">[class] sdf [class] aa </div>
```

"
and not this:
(the [] enclosure is a match)
"

```
<div [class]="myClass"> asd [class] 2 a a a a a a </div>   class
<div [class]="myClass"> [class] asd df </div>
<div [class]="myClass"> [class] </div>
<div [class]="myClass"> [class] sdf [class] aa </div>
<div [class]="myClass">[class] sdf [class] aa </div>
```

"
someone can help me? :)

Comment: after matching the word what do you want to do

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/WM8t6/1/

Comment: `so i can't just do $('.myClass').whatever` Actually you can. Much better to load this HTML into a jQuery object and traverse it properly than resort to regex for no reason

Answer (score 0):

**I think this is what you need:**

```
$html = <<< EOF
<div [class]="myClass"> asd [class] 2 a a a a a a </div>   class
<div [class]="myClass"> [class] asd df </div>
<div [class]="myClass"> [class2] </div>
<div [class]="myClass"> [class2] sdf [class] aa </div>
<div [class]="myClass">[class] sdf [class] aa </div>
EOF;

preg_match_all('/(\[class\]|\[class2\])(?=[^>]*(<|$))/i', $html, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result[1]); $i++) {
    echo $result[1][$i];
}
```

**OUTPUTS:**

```
[class][class][class2][class2][class][class][class]
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://ideone.com/aQhyLW)

**If you just need a javascript regex you can use:**

```
var myregexp = /(\[class\]|\[class2\])(?=[^>]*(<|$))/ig;
var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
while (match != null) {
    // matched text: match[0]
    // match start: match.index
    // capturing group n: match[n]
    match = myregexp.exec(subject);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".myClass").text(function () {
        return $(this).text().replace("class", "[class]"); 
    });
});
```

See the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LPC6n/